# why can't I use dynamic in ng-key in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" class="form-control">
```

and a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myaction('{{name}}')" type="button">submit</button>
```

but when I put {{name}} inside the ng-click this doesn't work, but if I put myaction('') or myaction('foo') or something, works.

when i put myaction('{{name}}'), the browser seems ok, but when i press the button this doesn't work, anybody know why this doesn't work?

thanks

Comment: What exactly does not work.  If you are trying to capture a name, the binding will do that as it is typed, so that an input with {{name}} would work, then use the myaction() to call some routine on the button press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ng-click directive doesn't need the binding syntax -- that is used for "regular" html.

Try:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myaction(name)" type="button">submit</button>
```